# The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a running Kubernetes on machine, while I want to access it by running any kubernetes releated commands (Example: sudo kubectl get nodes) I only get following error:

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Worth to mention that on this server I'm logged in as a seperate user with separatee home directory. In my home user directory I do not have .kube and it is located in the the main dir

Answer (score 0):

**Pod Selection**: Kubernetes does not expose individual pods directly through the NodePort. Instead, the NodePort exposes the service, and kube-proxy dynamically routes the traffic to one of the available pods based on its internal load-balancing mechanism.

**Single Node Scenario**: Even if all replicas are on the same node, the process remains the same. Kube-proxy on that node will distribute the traffic among all the pods matched by the service.

**Multiple Ports**: Each NodePort service is mapped to a single port on every node. If you have multiple services, each will get its own NodePort. Inside the cluster, pods can listen on any ports, and the service's targetPort will direct the traffic to the correct pod port.